# Highlight the first day of each month in jQuery-ui Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've had to make some modifications to my CSS for the jQuery datepicker. Unfortunately, along the way I have managed to have the first of EVERY month highlighted. What property do I need to look for? I have to remove styling from TODAY's date to perform other CSS. That I have been able to do. But I do not want this side effect....

Here is the line I added:

```
.ui-datepicker-current .ui-datepicker-today .ui-state-highlight { background: transparent !important;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`beforeShowDay`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) event for this. The primary function of this event is to enable or disable specific date(s) on the calendar. However, it can also be used to assign a special class to specific dates:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [true, date.getDate() == 1 ? "first-class" : ""];
    }
});
```

## [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/Fs6uu/)

Comment: I already have a function being used at "beforeShowDay" and it returns a value. Can I have "beforeShowDay" do 2 things such that I can include your suggestion?

Comment: Yes. It should return an array `[true/false, classname, tooltip text]`. 2nd and 3rd item in the returned array are optional. You need to add/modify the 2nd item.